# Using API to fecth the next list and display for users

Tags: react-native, expo

I am making a react-native app, I am fetching a list of movies from an API, and every time I press next I'm to supposed to get fetch the next list of movies, however, my code doesn't work correctly.

At first, you have to click on the button to fetch the first list like this:

```
<Button mode="contained" onPress={() => getMovieList()}>
  Get Movies
</Button>

const getMovieList= async () => {
  setLoading(true);

  await fetchMovies(url)
    .then(async (data) => {
      setData(data);
      // more code
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

The URL is:

```
const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/4/list/${listID}?page=1&api_key=${api_key}`;
```

I have written a function that I can use to fetch the list using the URL above,

```
const [listID, setListID] = useState(1);
```

After I fetch the first list I show them in a child component, like this:

```
<MyCompanyCard
  name={data.companyName}
  desc={data.desc}
  loadNextCompany={loadNextCompany}
  loadPrevCompany={loadPrevCompany}
  setListID={setListID}
  listID={listID}
/>
```

And also:

```
const loadNextCompany = async () => {
  setListID(listID + 1);
  await getMovieCompany();
};

const loadPrevCompany = async () => {
  setListID(listID - 1);
  await getMovieCompany();
};
```

In my child component, I call the `getNextOne` function and the problem is, although the URL changes but the content doesn't change and I have to press next, then I can see the next list and so on, the same applies for the `getPrevOne`. The problem is that every time I press next/prev I make an API call but I am not sure how to set the content to change accordingly.

=================

I was able to solve it by adding a useeffet like this:

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    await getMovieCompany();
  }, [listID]);
```

so now every time I add to listID then I fetch the url again and immdedialtly represnt the current items.

Comment: Where is `getMovieCompany` and just resetting the  `listID` for the URL wont work you'd have to call `getMovieList`. Why not implement a `useEffect` on `listID`?

Comment: Have you also tested to see if you're getting results back? I ask because I see `page=1`. Not familiar with the API but I'd implement status code checking in your code because there is no way, unless it's in more code, that you're able to see if what your code is doing is working.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ because I dont want it to run the useeffect when the page loads.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I do get results back, for example list 1 is marvel movies, and list 2 is oscar nominations, but for me when I load the movies I get list 1, when I press on next the url and listID changes but, the content stays the same (fetch dont work), when I press next , the on my console i see listID 3 but on my UI i see the oscar nominations. is is clear?

Comment: Can you provide an Expo Snack?

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I dont know how to do it :(

Comment: Replicate your app [here](https://snack.expo.dev/) and send the link so someone could clone it and debug.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    const getMovieList = useCallback(() => {
        const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/4/list/${listID}?page=1&api_key=${api_key}`;
        setLoading(true);    
        await fetchMovies(url)
        .then(async (data) => {
          setData(data);
          // more code
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });

      }, [listID]);
```

Comment: this works the same way, I some how need to update the url and then pass to my fucntion which is currently using it to fetch with the newt url

Comment: THanks but I manage to solve it and I put that on my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by adding a useeffet like this:

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    await getMovieCompany();
  }, [listID]);
```

so now every time I add to listID then I fetch the url again and immdedialtly represnt the current items.